# What is with the amounts of Monero in getbalance?

Tags: wallet

https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance

Why does it say `157443303037455077`? Is that an encoded amount or does someone really have that much monero?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it say 157443303037455077?

That's in *piconero*, the smallest denomination.

https://web.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/denominations.html

Comment: Also is that the same as what is spit out of the block reward and transaction fee? Or are those in other units? Like if the block reward says its 1 then is it 1 picomonero?

Comment: It depends where you're getting / viewing. All daemon and wallet RPC calls will use piconero.